# how to get sql table rows as header

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need the while results in php with row results

My SQL Table is like

```
ID | date      | material | Quantity
01 | 01/01/2018| abc      | 50
02 | 01/01/2018| abc      | 50
03 | 02/01/2018| def      | 50
04 | 03/01/2018| ghi      | 50
```

sql query:

```
select sum(Quantity) as 'Total Quantity',* group by date
```

I need the results as:

```
01/01/2018 | 02/01/2018 | 03/01/2018
100        |50          |50
```

This is my program:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo "<tr><td>".$row['Date']."</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>".$row1['Total Quantity']."</td></tr>";
}
```

but I Don't know how to get the date value in header

Comment: search about pivot table

Comment: can I get this reports in php using while fetch_assso

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: mysqli is the db

Comment: Just use 2 variables, and print the header from dates and data from quantities into them. The question is should missing dates also have a column or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you index your result set with the header values, you can easily access them using `array_keys()`:

```
$sql    = "SELECT SUM(Quantity) as quantity, date GROUP BY date ORDER BY date";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$rows = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $rows[$row['date']] = $row['quantity'];
}

$header = array_keys($rows);

echo "<table><tr>";
foreach ($header as $cell)
{
    echo "<th>$cell</th>";
}
echo "</tr><tr>";
foreach ($rows as $cell)
{
    echo "<td>$cell</td>";
}
echo "</tr></table>";
```

Comment: am getting this error: Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in tableSOD.php on line 21
Line Number 21: $header = array_keys(reset($rows));

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in tableSOD.php on line 25;
Line Number 25: foreach ($header as $cell)

Comment: Removed the `reset()` - Try again, please!

Comment: This while result adding only one row value. but there should be multiple results stored under the header key.

Comment: Your question implies exactly one data row. So you're pointing to a new problem now. Just ask a new question instead of discussing it here.

Comment: I couldn't raise new ticket. my results are in multiple rows when i do the same in sql. but I guess there can be one value stored against one header key (is it true?)

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this

```
$sql = "SELECT sum(Quantity) as Total_Quantity ,date from [Table] group by date order by date";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   echo $row['date']." ";
   echo $row['Total_Quantity']." ";
}
```

(Not Tested but this is how it should work)

Comment: But how can I get the date as column header.

Comment: you will get the date by adding it to the select statement EDIT: ah i see you want a HTML Table - ok then the answer is right down from @nibra!